# RestKit JSON Mapping

Tags: ios, json, swift, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have given JSON and cannot parse partial data. It seems dictionary into dictionary:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 6796,
            "title": "my title",
            "description": "desc",
            "code": "12345",
            "valueType": "null",
            "discounts": [
                {
                    "minPrice": null,
                    "maxPrice": null,
                    "value": 20,
                    "avail": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the latest version of RESTKit but I cannot properly parse under `discounts`.

my RestKit settings are:

```
responseMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([

            "id"                        : "id",
            "code"                      : "code",
            "title"                     : "title",
            "valueType"                 : "valueType",
            "description"               : "desc",
            "discounts.minPrice"        : "minPrice",
            "discounts.maxPrice"        : "maxPrice",
            "discounts.value"           : "value",
            "discounts.avail"    : "avail",
            ])
```

but all values below discounts always return Nil. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly map using `discounts.XXX` because `discounts` is an array and you have no way to index into that array and extract a single value.

You either need to change the source JSON to compress the values out of the dictionary, or create a custom object that you can map each item in the `discounts` array to.

Technically you could map the whole `discounts` array, which would give you an array of dictionaries, that you could then unpack in the setter method, but the array of custom objects is usually a better approach.

Comment: It helped me. I have mapped with mapping relationship nested array as separated dictionary.